# Fetch Data from master table based on child table condition in sql server

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Need to fetch data from master table based on child table condition.

Master Table:-

```
ID Name Address

1   abc   xyz
2   abs   txt
3   aui   tre
4   pop   top
5   the   tre
6   pot   tos
7   pog   sop
8   pat   top
9   bat   cric
10  not   kot
```

Child Table:-

```
chid shootid imagename       IDFK
101   234    123ab.jpg        3
102   234    54abcab.jpg      3
103   235    123abc.jpg       3
104   236    12390acb.jpg     Null
105   235    12332aab.jpg     8
106   234    123786ab.jpg     4
107   234    54789abcab.jpg   10
108   235    122343abc.jpg    10
109   235    122123acb.jpg    4
110   234    12123aab.jpg     9
111   234    1223ab.jpg       Null
112   233    5432abcab.jpg    Null
113   235    1239abc.jpg      Null
114   236    1238acb.jpg      2
115   236    12356aab.jpg     2
116   236    1235ab.jpg       2
117   236    545abcab.jpg     Null
118   237    1233abc.jpg      1
119   237    1223acb.jpg      1
120   237    1123aab.jpg      1
```

In Child table IDFK is the foreign key and ID in Master table is the primary key of that.
Now i want to show those name from master table that doesn't exist on child table filter on shootid like `where childtable.Shootid=234`. I tried but not find the desired output.Every time it just return's the same out for different shootid as well.

Please help me and show me the right query for that.

Comment: Please add desired output using rows from the example tables that you gave. You have multiple IDFK values for shoot 234, are you trying to get the rows from Master that correspond to those values, or that DON'T correspond to those values?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I am understand you well or not but I think this is what you want,

```
Select * from [master] m
where m.ID not in (Select IDFK from detail where shootid=234)
```

Comment: Would your write your desired output

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
 Select distinct m.name from master m LEFT OUTER JOIN child c
     ON m.id = c.id and 
        c.shootid=234    
    where 
     c.id is null
```

Comment: sorry to say what that does not give me desired output,,i tried this way as well.